# How are 2D collision forces calculated?

Tags: physics, circles, vectors, mathematical-physics

Between 2 circles of the same radii, how can I calculate the collision forces to apply to each of the 2 circles? I have position, mass, and velocity for each of the circles.

Here's what I have currently:

```
Vector2 Direction = (CircleA.position - CircleB.position).normalized;
Direction = Direction.AbsoluteValue();
Vector2 Force1 = New Vector2(CircleA.Vel.x * CircleA.Mass * Direction.x, *same thing for y*);
Vector2 Force2 = new Vector2(CircleB.Vel.x * CircleB.Mass * Direction.x, *same thing for y*);

CircleA.ApplyForce (Force2 - Force1);
CircleB.ApplyForce (Force1 - Force2);
```

Is this somewhere close to correct or do I have it completely wrong? Sorry I'm a bit of a newbie with physics. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I couldn't find any straightforward online resources.